# Displaying results in image labeling in Firebase ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, image-processing, firebase-mlkit

The app isn't displaying any result on screen, however the information is visualized on the log.

Here are the project dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:18.0.0'

implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
```

And Here is the code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_label_image)
    requestedOrientation=(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

    btn_label.setOnClickListener { 
        labelCamera_view.start()
        labelCamera_view.captureImage()
    }

    labelCamera_view.addCameraKitListener(object :CameraKitEventListener{
        override fun onVideo(p0: CameraKitVideo?) {

        }

        override fun onEvent(p0: CameraKitEvent?) {

        }

        override fun onImage(p0: CameraKitImage?) {
            var bitmap=p0!!.bitmap
            bitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,labelCamera_view.width,labelCamera_view.height,false)
            labelCamera_view.stop()

            runLabel(bitmap)
        }

        override fun onError(p0: CameraKitError?) {

        }
    })
}

private fun runLabel(bitmap: Bitmap?) {

    val image=FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)

    val options=FirebaseVisionOnDeviceImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
        .setConfidenceThreshold(0.8f)
        .build()

    val detector=FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceImageLabeler(options)
    detector.processImage(image)
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("EDMTERROR",e.message) }
        .addOnSuccessListener { result-> processResultFromDevice(result) }

}


private fun processResultFromDevice(result: List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>) {
        for (label in result) {
            val text = label.text
            val entityId = label.entityId
            val confidence = label.confidence
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i("SAFE", "success")

            print("result : $text ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write in all uppercase letters, it is interpreted as screaming. Please [edit] your question to be more polite!

Comment: Creating a bunch of toasts in a loop looks like a bug. How are you going to see any of them except the last one? You may also want to verify that you're on the UI thread when trying to show the toast.